# Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-function-app

I am calling Logic App from Azure Function App using HttpClient call. Till yesterday Logic App and Function App both worked fine. But today, function app unable to call logic app.

I got below error in Function app

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>
> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond. A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond.

When I test function app locally, it executed successfully and called logic app aswell without any issues. Getting issue only post deployment.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when my application had no security protocol defined. Then I had to switch my application to use TLS 1.2. Now a days servers are turning older protocols off.

If you are having the same problem then you can define a protocol by simply adding the following like to the `Application_Start` method in your `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```